# Adding up review totals in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am creating a website that helps you find doctors. I would like the doctors to have a field in their model that has an overall rating, friendliness rating, cleanliness rating, satisfaction rating, and responsiveness rating. All of these ratings will be a number calculated by adding up all of their review (another model) and populating these fields using a sum calculation. My question is, how do I accomplish this when all of my reviews are a separate model that is virtually populated on the doctor's model in a controller? Is there some way to add up all of the reviews for a specific doctor ID and then calculate averages on the ratings and then update the doctor with this information?

Here is my doctor model:

```
const prothesistSchema = mongoose.Schema(


{
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A user must have a name'],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A user must have an email'],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email'],
    },
    ratingsAverage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 4.5,
      min: [1, 'Rating must be above 1.0'],
      max: [5, 'Rating must be below 5.0'],
    },

    

  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);


prothesistSchema.virtual('reviews', {
  ref: 'Review',
  foreignField: 'prosthetistID',
  localField: '_id',
});


const Prothesist = mongoose.model('Prothesist', prothesistSchema);
```

Here are the reviews I am trying to calculate averages off of:

```
const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(


{
    review: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A review must have a review!!!'],
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0.5,
      max: 5,
    },
    friendliness: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0.5,
      max: 5,
    },
    cleanliness: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0.5,
      max: 5,
    },
    satisfaction: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0.5,
      max: 5,
    },
    responsiveness: {
      type: Number,
      min: 0.5,
      max: 5,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    prosthetistID: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Prothesist',
      required: [true, 'Review must belong to a prosthetist!'],
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      require: [true, 'Each review must have an associated user!'],
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

reviewSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  const query = [
    // { path: 'tour', select: 'name' },
    { path: 'user', select: 'name photo activityLevel age amputationInfo' },
  ];
  this.populate(query);
  next();
});

const Review = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

2 approaches here:

The first one would be keeping a running score and keep editing that instead of calculating from the beginning. I am assuming this is what big sites (like Yelp or Google) are doing, since it's way more scalable.

The second and most obvious approach would be, iterating over all the reviews every time a review gets added to calculate new numbers.

Let's dissect the first one:

1. save a running score for every field under every doctor's listing
2. trigger your updateRatings function on every addition to the reviews
3. this function should:

- Get current score
- Multiply it by the reviews.length
- Add the currentReviewRating
- Divide by review.length+1 to get the new average
- Save that as a new average to use later

The second one would be very straight forward:

```
let avg = avg([...reviews.field]) => ( sum(arr) / length(arr) );
```